# What if I have no results to display on a map after calling Google Distance Matrix API

Tags: google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I would like to develop a service, using Google Distance Matrix API, where a user can enter their current location and a map will be displayed showing how many other users from their group have addresses in the same general area. For privacy reasons, I do not want to show any other details (location, name, address etc.) of those other users just the number of people.
In order to ascertain this information I was intending to make a call to the API and displaying under the map of their area a message like "There are 5 other people within a 3 minute drive of your address".
Can anybody tell me whether this meets the API limitation:

> The Google Maps Distance Matrix API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map. It is prohibited to use Google Maps Distance Matrix API data without displaying a Google map

If my requirements of the API are not acceptable, could anybody suggest another publicly available API that I could use in its place?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding.

Comment: He asks for a publicly available Api that gives you distance from given locations. It's a specific task and he didn't ask general recommendations. Api requests regards code too, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks to Alex for the pointer to [YourNavigation](http://www.yournavigation.org/about.htm), I am currently also looking at the following APIs:
[OpenRouteService](https://maps.openrouteservice.org) ,
[Graphhopper](https://graphhopper.com) and
[MapQuest](https://developer.mapquest.com)

Answer (score 1):

[Yournavigation](http://www.yournavigation.org/about.html) Api gives you distance from given points.

Try this request [example](http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&flat=41.8963418&flon=12.4949566&tlat=41.9035108&tlon=12.4793949&fast=0&layer=mapnik&instructions=1).

You can find their usage policy [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS#Usage).
They said that there are no limitations on usage, except those regarding overload:

> The routing API is open and freely available for everyone under the condition that you don't overload the server. Overloading the server in this context means: more then 1 request per second for sustained periods of time. Bursting multiple requests for short time-periods is not a problem though